# MariaDB throws an error when I try to use FOR UPDATE NOWAIT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select-for-update

I am getting below error when I try to use `NOWAIT` in my select query.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOWAIT' at line 1`

My Mariadb version is `10.2.29-MariaDB-1:10.2.29+maria~bionic`

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The `NOWAIT` option was added in MariaDB 10.3.0.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, Do you have any other solution that I can use? 
I am not in a position to upgrade the version at this moment.

Comment: I'm curious.  What is your use case for desiring `NOWAIT`?

Answer (score 0):

The `WAIT` keyword was added in MariaDB 10.3.0.

Prior to that, the wait to control the lock wait time is by setting the variables [`lock_wait_timeout`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#lock_wait_timeout) or [`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_lock_wait_timeout). Setting the appropriate variable to `0` is equivalent to `NOWAIT`.